# Call to ExAllocatePoolWithTag never returns

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, kernel-module, kernel32

I am having some issues with my virtualHBA driver on Windows Server 2016. A ran the HLK crashdump support test. *3 times out of 10 the test passed*. **In those 3 failing tests, the crashdump hangs at 0% while taking Complete dump, or Kernel dump or minidump**.

By kernel debugging my code, I found that the call to `ExAllocatePoolWithTag()`  for buffer allocation never actually returns.

Below is the statement which **never returns**.

```
pDeviceExtension->pcmdbuf=(struct mycmdrsp *)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPoolCacheAligned,pcmdqSignalSize,((ULONG)'TA1'));
```

I searched on the web regarding this. However, all of the found pages are focusing on this function returning **NULL** which in my case never returns.

Any help on how to move forward would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't allocate memory in crash dump mode. You're running at HIGH_LEVEL with interrupts disabled and so you're calling this API at the wrong IRQL.

The typical solution for a hardware adapter is to set the RequestedDumpBufferSize in the PORT_CONFIGURATION_INFORMATION structure during the normal HwFindAdapter call. Then when you're called again in crash dump mode you use the CrashDumpRegion field to get your dump buffer allocation. You then need to write your own "crash dump mode only" allocator to allocate buffers out of this memory region.

It's a huge pain, especially given that it's difficult/impossible to know how much memory you're ultimately going to need. I usually calculate some minimal configuration overhead (i.e. 1 channel, 8 I/O requests at a time, etc.) and then add in a registry configurable slush. The only benefit is that the environment is stripped down so you don't need to be in your all singing, all dancing configuration.

Comment: If what you are saying is correct than it should have failed at exactly the same point EVERYTIME. However, as I have mentioned above, the crashdump test passes 4/10 times, and that to either while taking Complete dump, or while taking kernel dump (after successfully completing the Complete Dump test).

Comment: I'm not guessing. Check the IRQL before the call and then check the documentation. The results of what you are doing are architecturally undefined, the fact that it works sometimes does not make it correct.

Comment: I have checked the IRQL, and as you have said, I found it to be at HIGH_LEVEL (with !irql 1. For all other processors it is showing LOW_LEVEL) I am not sure which processor my thread is currently running. Also, I didn't find the relevant MSDN documentation which you are referring to. If possible, PLEASE SHARE THE RELEVANT LINKS, because the links which I found mostly talks about very high level of crashdump drivers and not VERY DETAILED INTERNALS of it.

Comment: `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` cna be called only when IRQL <= DISPATCH_LEVEL which does not mean it automatically bugchecks when you attempt to break this rule (for example, you can successfully lock executive resources on DISPATCH_LEVEL, however, very nasty things may emerge later). If your code is executing inside something like bug check callback, the documentation is strict – you are running at HIGH_LEVEL, period.

Comment: I don't know of any detailed description of this on MSDN. Google "crash dump miniport" and start looking through the result. I've written several of these types of drivers (and have the scars to prove it!). Basically just don't expect much in the system to work or much detailed documentation

Comment: @snoone I am working on it accordingly. However, since I am new to this area, I am facing some difficulty in allocating tagged buffers from the memory region. I have posted this in another stackoverflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743014/how-to-split-reserved-memory-into-3-buffers-in-kernel-space . Please help.